# android - error get FileBody(sourceFile) in marshmallow when will upload image and get exif

Tags: php, android

I'm getting error using `FileBody(sourceFile)`in marshmallow but no kitkat.. I trying to upload image to server and get the exif in php.. how I can fix that?

this code to parsing sourcefile to php

```
entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
```

and this is value of `FileBody(sourceFile)` when i show it to log
this for kitkat

```
org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody@42355548

[ 11-24 10:07:42.743   176:  344 D/         ]
                                                                                     RIL_onMultiClientUnsolicitedResponse:

 [ 11-24 10:07:42.743   176:  344 E/         ]
                                                                                     unsupported multiclient unsolicited response code 1002

[ 11-24 10:07:42.743   176:  344 D/         ]
                                                                                     RIL_onMultiClientUnsolicitedResponse:

[ 11-24 10:07:42.743   176:  344 E/         ]
                                                                                     unsupported multiclient unsolicited response code 1002
```

and this for marshmallow

```
org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody@aa4dbf9

[ 11-24 10:04:45.819  1013: 2627 W/         ]
                                               Unable to open '/system/framework/ifaamanager.jar': No such file or directory
```